# Primefaces Input Text Area Rows not working

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

I make an `<p:inputTextArea>` and i want to set Rows of that, but I don't know why it's not working. Here is my xhtml code :

```
<h:form id="contactUsForm">
    <div class="ui-fluid p-formgrid p-grid">
        <div class="p-field p-col-12">
            <p:outputLabel style="font-size:16px !important;" for="email" value="Email"/>
            <p:inputText id="email" value="#{contactUsBacking.email}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="p-field p-col-12">
            <p:outputLabel style="font-size:16px !important;" for="question" value="Question"/>
            <p:inputTextarea id="question" rows="4" value="#{contactUsBacking.question}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding `cols="80"` too?  What about i wonder if `p-field` style is affecting it.

Comment: I've tried to add cols="80" too but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with add `min-height` on style Thank you!